# Same occupation measure $\Rightarrow$ same trajectory

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Let $f$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ vector field (VF) on a compact subset $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. $M$ inherits the Euclidean metric. We define a dynamical system by
$$\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t))$$
The occupation measure is defined as
$$
    \mu_{x_{0}, T}^f(B)  
     \, = \, \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} \mathbb{1}_{B}(x(s)) \, d s 
$$

where $x(t)$ is a trajectory with $t \in [0, T]$, starting from $x_0$, $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is some Borel measurable set, and $\mathbb{1} \,$ denotes an indicator function. By $\Gamma_{x_0}^f=\{x(t)|t \in T\}$ we denote a trajectory.

If two vector fields $f,g$ have equal occupation measures for all times $T$, can we conclude that the underlying trajectories are equal?
In other words:
$$ \mu_{x_{0}, T}^f(B) =\mu_{x_{0}, T}^g(B) \ \forall T \in \mathbb{R}, \forall B \quad \Rightarrow \quad \Gamma_{x_0}^f=\Gamma_{x_0}^g  $$